# Use Chi-Squared statistic in pymc3

Tags: pymc3, mcmc, chi-squared, model-fitting

I am trying to use PyMC3 to fit a model to some observed data. This model is based on external code (interfaced via theano.ops.as_op), and depends on multiple parameters that should be fit by the MCMC process. Since the gradient of the external code cannot be determined, I use the Metropolis-Hastings sampler.

I have established Uniform priors for my inputs, and generate a model using my custom code. However, I want to compare the simulated data to my observations (a 3D np.ndarray) using the chi-squared statistic (sum of the squares of data-model/sigma^2) to obtain a log-likelihood. When the MCMC samples are drawn, this should lead to the trace converging on the best values of each parameter.

My model is explained in the following semi-pseudocode (if that's even a word):

```
import pymc3 as pm
#Some stuff setting up the data, preparing some functions etc.

@theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[input types],otypes = [output types])
def make_model(inputs):
    #Wrapper to external code to generate simulated data
    return simulated data

model = pm.model()
with model:
    #priors for 13 input parameters
    simData = make_model(inputs)
```

I now want to obtain the chi-squared logLikelihood for this model versus the data, which I think can be done using pm.ChiSquared, however I do not see how to combine the data, model and this distribution together to cause the sampler to perform correctly. I would guess it might look something like:

```
    chiSq = pm.ChiSquared(nu=data.size, observed = (data-simData)**2/err**2)
    trace = pm.sample(1000)
```

Is this correct? In running previous tests, I have found the samples appear to be simply drawn from the priors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A chi-squared test is a "frequentist" test, of course there is a Bayesian counterpart (but you do not need to compute the chi-square values or p-values). I am not sure want you want to do. Could you give some more details about your data and what do you want to achieve? Do you have a contingency table?

Comment: Thanks @aloctavodia. I'm trying to find the best-fitting parameters for the model to my observed data, where goodness of fit is defined by the chi-squared statistic (corrected for some covariance between samples). I'm not trying to perform a chi-squared test, only to find the minimum of the Chi-squared statistic, and the contours of fixed chi-squared around this, as in eg. the section on Parameter Estimation from http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~cblake/StatsLecture3.pdf, where instead of using a grid, I use an MCMC method for sampling.

Comment: How do you think you simdata is distributed?

Comment: From your reference: "The most likely (“best-fitting”) values of (a,b) are found by minimizing the chi-squared statistic". In a Bayesian setting, the “best-fitting” values of (a,b) are found by applying Bayes' theorem, no need to use a chi-squared statistic. Using a linear model as example, `data = a simData + b + c` you put priors over `a`, `b` and `c` and your likelihood will be something like `yl = pm.Normal('yl', mu=a simData + b, sd=c, observed= data)` here I am assuming your data follows a Gaussian distribution, but you are free to choose a different distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Taking [aloctavodia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815542/aloctavodia)'s advice, I was able to get parameter estimates for some toy exponential data using a `pm.Normal` likelihood. Using a `pm.ChiSquared` likelihood as the OP suggested, the model converged to correct values, but the posteriors on the parameters were roughly three times as broad. Here's the code for the model; I first generated data and then fit with PyMC3.

```
# Draw `nPoints` observed data points `y_obs` from the function
#     3. + 18. * numpy.exp(-.2 * x)
# with the points evaluated at `x_obs`
#     x_obs = numpy.linspace(0, 100, nPoints)
# Add Normal(mu=0,sd=`cov`) noise to each point in `y_obs`
# Then instantiate PyMC3 model for fit:

def YModel(x, c, a, l):
  # exponential model expected to describe the data
  mu = c + a * pm.math.exp(-l * x)
  return mu

def logp(y_mod, y_obs):
  # Normal distribution likelihood
  return pm.Normal.dist(mu = y_mod, sd = cov).logp(y_obs)
  # Chi squared likelihood (to use, comment preceding line & uncomment next 2 lines)
  #chi2 = chi2 = pm.math.sum( ((y_mod - y_obs)/cov)**2 )
  #return pm.ChiSquared.dist(nu = nPoints).logp(chi2)

with pm.Model() as model:
  c = pm.Uniform('constant', lower = 0., upper = 10., testval = 5.)
  a = pm.Uniform('amplitude', lower = 0., upper = 50., testval = 25.)
  l = pm.Uniform('lambda', lower = 0., upper = 10., testval = 5.)
  y_mod = YModel(x_obs, c, a, l)
  L = pm.DensityDist('L', logp, observed = {'y_mod': y_mod, 'y_obs': y_obs}, testval = {'y_mod': y_mod, 'y_obs': y_obs})
  step = pm.Metropolis([c, a, l])
  trace = pm.sample(draws = 10000, step = step)
```

The above model converged, but I found that success was sensitive to the bounds on the priors and the initial guesses on those parameters.

```
        mean        sd  mc_error    hpd_2.5   hpd_97.5   n_eff      Rhat
c   3.184397  0.111933  0.002563   2.958383   3.397741  1834.0  1.000260
a  18.276887  0.747706  0.019857  16.882025  19.762849  1343.0  1.000411
l   0.200201  0.013486  0.000361   0.174800   0.226480  1282.0  0.999991
```

(Edited: I had forgotten to sum the squares of the normalized residuals for `chi2`)

Comment: Hi @curiousStudent. I am trying to reproduce your example above, but constantly getting an error "MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start from 0), used to compute sigmoid(constant_interval__), was not provided and not given a value. Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high', for more information on this error."
If it is not too much to ask, could you provide minimum working example